# Combining Base URL in literals with Relative URLS that are in a set

Tags: python, python-3.x, url

I have a set() of relative links that I need to combine to a base link so that it becomes an absolute link

This is the code that is creating the set() with the relative link.  I want to combine all with the base link ex:"https:\www.census.gov"

```
linker_set = set() 
for link in soup.find_all('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("^/")}):         
    print(link.get('href')) 
    linker_set.add(link.get('href'))
```

Comment: Add the code to the question,not in comment.

Answer (score 1):

Just set the base link as a variable and add the strings.

```
base_url = 'https://www.census.gov'

linker_set = set() 
for link in soup.find_all('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("^/")}):
    print(link.get('href')) 
    # Store link string as variable
    href_link = link.get('href')
    # Add base url to href link
    new_link = base_url + href_link
    linker_set.add(new_link)
```